# Search for similar sounding words in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, hashmap

I am making an app in react native, and am getting a text output from the 'react-native-voice/voice' library to perform a speech to text conversion. It returns a list of strings `results` that I am able to parse through. I was able to parse through it, and save the words as a list in wordsInResults.

```
wordsInResults = results.flatMap(result => result.toLowerCase().split(' '));
```

I am then searching through this wordsInResults to search through an array 'keywordList'

```
keywordList= ['strategy', 'bullish', 'bearish']
```

using the following function

```
const keywordsInResults = Array.from(new Set(wordsInResults.filter(word => 
      keywordList.map(item => item.toLowerCase()).includes(word)
    )));
```

This function works fine for finding the keywords, but while testing, I see that when I say the words 'bullish' and 'bearish', it sometimes returns the words 'bolish, police, or polish' and 'barrage, barish, or barris' respectively.

To try to fix this, I first tried searching for some phonetics library that could do a string 'distance' comparison, but it seems none of them worked with React Native.
I then resorted to making a csv file 'keywords.csv' that contained a comma separated list of similarly pronounced words, where each row's first word was the intended word, and all words after were 'similar' sounding words.

```
strategy, strategies, strateg, strata
bullish, bolish, police, polish
bearish, barrage, barish, barris
```

I tried using RNFS and Papaparse to parse through this file and create a hashMap that contains all the words

```
const csvFilePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/../../csvComponents/keywords.csv';
    const fileContents = await RNFS.readFile(csvFilePath, 'utf8');
    const csvData = Papa.parse(fileContents, {header: false}).data;
    const hashMap = {};
    csvData.forEach(row => {
      const firstWord = row[0];
      row.forEach(word => {
        hashMap[word] = firstWord;
      });
    });
```

And then creating keywordsInResults using

```
const keywordsInResults = Array.from(new Set(wordsInResults.filter(word => {
      if (hashMap[word]) {
        return hashMap[word];
      }
      return [];
    })));
```

However, I keep getting errors that I cannot fix.
One of which is:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I would appreciate advice on Phonetics libraries for React-native, fixing the code I already have or any other improvements you would suggest.